# Fire button click event when there are multiple classes on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I fire a button click event when a particular button is pressed (in this case the accept button).

I've tried the following but with little success:

**Javascript**

```
$('.notification-expand .Request .active-item > .accept-button').click(function () {
    alert("hello");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="notification-expand Request active-item" style="display: block;">
    <div class="notification-body"></div>
    <br>
    <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success accept-button btn-sm">Accept</button>
    </p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 expand-col">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning barter-button btn-sm">Barter</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 expand-col">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger reject-button btn-sm">Reject</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wjwwgz6p/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have error in your selector , it should look like this:

```
$('.notification-expand.Request.active-item .accept-button').click(function () {
    alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: Under the same logic would it be possible to do this: `$('.notification-expand.Request.active-item .accept-button, .notification-expand.Reject.active-item .accept-button').click(function() {
  alert("hello");
 });`

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate all classes without spaces to catch your target button

```
$('button.accept-button', '.notification-expand.Request.active-item').click(function () {
    alert("hello");
});
```

See the updated [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/wjwwgz6p/1/)

Notice the syntax of **".className1.className2"** instead of **".className1 .className2"**

Comment: If I wanted to reference `button.accept-button` in `.notification-expand.Reject.active-item`, how would I go about doing it? Can it be done in the same line?

Comment: You can use event delegation, to bind click event on `.notification-expand.Reject.active-item` element, and catch only the target one marked with `.accept-button` class
[updated snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/wjwwgz6p/3/)

Comment: Thanks. The snippet posted doesn't show it however.

Comment: Sorry, I saw Reject and Request the same word :)
Below is the updated one
[snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/wjwwgz6p/4/)

Answer (score 1):

should be something like:

```
$('button.accept-button').click(function(){ ... });
```

there is really no need to go down the whole list if this is the whole code

----edit----

so when there are more items but only 1 active(i guess) then just target the active-item class:

```
$('div.active-item button.accept-button').click(function(){ ... });
```

Comment: There are other elements, so it is necessary to tell apart the .active item from the others...

Comment: Why not give that button an id?

Answer (score 1):

Just give the button an id and reference back to that.

**HTML**

```
<button id="btnSubmitData"> Ok Button </button>
```

**JQuery Code**

```
$('#btnSubmitData').click(function(){ ... });
```

You can also have multiple button Ids bind to the same event:

```
$('#btnAccept, #btnReject, #btnWarning').click(function () {
        alert("hello");
    });
```

Take a look at the updated [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjwwgz6p/2/).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('.accept-button', $('.notification-expand.active-item')).click(function () {
    alert("hello");
});
```

or

```
$('.notification-expand.active-item')).find('.accept-button').click(function () {
    alert("hello");
});
```